# How do I contact Google after my search result rankings got heavily downgraded?

Tags: google-search, ranking

I have a website with lots of traffic from 5+ languages, and today suddenly I found that every keyword (every one of them, not just in one language) got downgraded. Many of my keywords on the 1st result went down to 20th ~ 30th. (Yes, I could still find them after going next a few pages)

I didn't do anything, so I am afraid it's a mistake. How can I contact Google to ask them to review this?

Comment: Short answer? You can't. Otherwise, Google will have everyone contacting them. You can, however, bring it up on the Google forums and seek an answer there. Sometimes, a Google employee will jump in. However, that is generally reserved for serious issues where Google may have a algo problem.

Comment: It would be nice if Google were more open and informational. As it is, it keeps honest people guessing.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo As Michal G suggested, check for a [Manual Actions Report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604824?hl=en), and if you see one and have corrected the issues, [request reconsideration of your site](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration). If you don't, then check for other possible reasons (such as any changes in your site, keyword trends, or competitors...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

First you should look at your Google Search Console.
Check for suspicious things like:

- Incorrect_robots.txt_ config
- Strange indexing errors
- A manual penalty from Google (if  Google decided to downgrade your position because of blackhat SEO techniques for example, you will see some info there)

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see any "manual penalty". Besides I didn't try any blockhat SEO because my rankings are already very high for years. I just noticed that I have some hreflang errors since Dec 6. I will wait for some updates.

Comment: manual penalty  (it's called manual action) is  here  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/manual-action?utm_source=support.google.com/webmasters/&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6155685

Comment: Got. Thanks. I didn't find any information there. I will update this question when I have any new information.

Comment: Well, all my rankings got back now.

According to the "International Targeting" panel, I noticed that I misconfigured 723 of my 9906 hreflang tags. The detailed mistake is that I taken 'cn' for 'zh-Hans'. And some of my hreflang tags got "no return tags" - how ever I did set them up. I don't know why.

After removing all the hreflang tags, the rankings got back.